# pivot_longer with names_pattern and pairs of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot-table, tidyr, data-manipulation

I am trying to figure out how to use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` in the following example. This is how the original table called `dat_plot` is structured like:

```
   year organizational_based action_based ideological_based share_org_based share_ideo_based share_act_based
  <dbl>                <dbl>        <dbl>             <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>
1  1956                    1            0                 0               2               95              95
2  2000                    0            0                 0              92               87              91
```

also here:

```
dat_plot <- structure(list(year = c(1956, 2000), organizational_based = c(1, 
0), action_based = c(0, 0), ideological_based = c(0, 0), share_org_based = c(2, 
92), share_ideo_based = c(95, 87), share_act_based = c(95, 91
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I would like to turn it into the long format, in the following way:

```
  year          based based_value      share share_value
1 1956 organizational           1  org_based           2
2 1956         action           0 ideo_based          95
3 1956    ideological           0  act_based          95
4 2000 organizational           0  org_based          92
5 2000         action           0 ideo_based          87
6 2000    ideological           0  act_based          91
```

or, with `dput`:

```
solution <- structure(list(year = c(1956, 1956, 1956, 2000, 2000, 2000), 
    based = c("organizational", "action", "ideological", "organizational", 
    "action", "ideological"), based_value = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), share = c("org_based", "ideo_based", "act_based", "org_based", 
    "ideo_based", "act_based"), share_value = c(2, 95, 95, 92, 
    87, 91)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I thought I have to work with `names_pattern`, what I have tried is something like this, but if you try you will see, that it is not what I want:

```
pivot_longer(data=dat_plot, cols=c("share_org_based", "share_ideo_based", "share_act_based",
                    "organizational_based", "action_based", "ideological_based"),
             names_pattern = c("(share_[A-Za-z]+)([A-Za-z]+_based)"),
             names_to = c("share", ".value"),
             values_to = "value")
```

I am grateful for any leads as to how `names_pattern` works, or what am I missing.

Comment: One place you might have trouble is the fact that your column names don't match exactly, e.g. you want "organizational" and "org" to match. You also might want to mark off column types as being share or based: right now you have shares marked, but not the others. For that, you might need to rename your columns first. Why do you have action paired with ideo, and ideological paired with act?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use two `pivot_longer`s:

```
dat_plot %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("share"), names_to = "share", names_prefix = "share_", values_to = "share_value") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = ends_with("based"), names_to = "based", names_pattern = "(.*)_based", values_to = "based_value") %>% 
  filter(substr(share, 1, 3) == substr(based, 1, 3))
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 5
   year share      share_value based          based_value
  <dbl> <chr>            <dbl> <chr>                <dbl>
1  1956 org_based            2 organizational           1
2  1956 ideo_based          95 ideological              0
3  1956 act_based           95 action                   0
4  2000 org_based           92 organizational           0
5  2000 ideo_based          87 ideological              0
6  2000 act_based           91 action                   0
```

Answer (score 2):

Or another option is `to_long` from `sjmisc`

```
library(sjmisc)
dat_plot %>%
   to_long(keys = c("based", "share"), 
   values = c("value_based", "value_share"), names(.)[2:4], names(.)[5:7] ) 
  year                based value_based            share value_share
1 1956 organizational_based           1  share_org_based           2
2 2000 organizational_based           0  share_org_based          92
3 1956         action_based           0 share_ideo_based          95
4 2000         action_based           0 share_ideo_based          87
5 1956    ideological_based           0  share_act_based          95
6 2000    ideological_based           0  share_act_based          91
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `tidyverse` approach: Data is ordered alphabetically by `based`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat_plot %>%
  pivot_longer(-year) %>% 
  arrange(name) %>% 
  mutate(name = str_remove_all(name, "share_")) %>% 
  group_by(group = rep(row_number(), each=6, length.out = n())) %>% 
  mutate(name = ifelse(group==1, str_remove_all(name, "_based"), name)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = c(name, value), values_fn = list) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(name_1, name_2, value_1, value_2)) %>% 
  select(year, based=name_1, based_value=value_1, share=name_2, share_value=value_2)
```

```
 year based          based_value share      share_value
  <dbl> <chr>                <dbl> <chr>            <dbl>
1  1956 action                   0 act_based           95
2  1956 ideological              0 ideo_based          95
3  1956 organizational           1 org_based            2
4  2000 action                   0 act_based           91
5  2000 ideological              0 ideo_based          87
6  2000 organizational           0 org_based           92
```